# Review on core EF repository method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What do you think about this core EF method ?

Also, Notice that it returns IQueryable:

Could that be a performance danger when extended improperly ? How ?

Please accept the fact that `Includes` and `OrderBy` parameters are `string` type.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntitySetMultipleTables(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> WhereExpression = null,
                                                string OrderBy = null,
                                                int TotalResults = int.MaxValue, int SkippedResults = 0, string[] Includes = null)
    {
        if (OrderBy != null)
        {
            string orderbyProperty = OrderBy;
            if (OrderBy.IndexOf(' ') > -1) // Direction
            {
                orderbyProperty = OrderBy.Substring(0, OrderBy.IndexOf(' '));
            }

            if (typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(orderbyProperty) == null)
                OrderBy = null;
        }
        if ((SkippedResults > 0) && (OrderBy == null))
        {
            OrderBy = GetPrimaryKeyName();
        }

        //Base EntitySet
        IQueryable<TEntity> results;
        ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectSetResults = Context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        if (Includes == null)
            results = objectSetResults.AsQueryable();
        else
        {
            foreach (var include in Includes)
            {
                objectSetResults = objectSetResults.Include(include.Trim());
            }
            results = objectSetResults.AsQueryable();
        }

        //Filter by Where Expression
        if (WhereExpression != null)
            results = results.Where(WhereExpression);

        //Order Results
        if (OrderBy != null)
        {
            results = results.OrderBy(OrderBy);
        }

        //Skip Records
        if (SkippedResults > 0)
            results = results.Skip(SkippedResults);

        //Take Specific Amount of records
        if (TotalResults != int.MaxValue)
            results = results.Take(TotalResults);

        //Run the LINQ Query and return the results
        return results;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this code works (I had to invent `GetPrimaryKeyName`) and I can't find a `IQueryable<T>` that has an `OrderBy` that takes a string parameter.  So faking it as much as possible, I came up with this:

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntitySetMultipleTables(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereExpression = null,
        string orderBy = null,
        int? totalResults = null,
        int? skippedResults = null,
        string[] includes = null)
    {
        PropertyInfo orderbyProperty;
        int directionIndex;

        if (orderBy == null)
        {
            directionIndex = -1;
            orderbyProperty = null;
        }
        else
        {
            directionIndex = orderBy.IndexOf(' ');

            // Direction.
            if (directionIndex > -1)
            {
                orderBy = orderBy.Substring(0, directionIndex);
            }

            orderbyProperty = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(orderBy);
        }

        if ((skippedResults != null) && ((int)skippedResults > 0) && (orderbyProperty == null))
        {
            orderbyProperty = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(GetPrimaryKeyName());
        }

        // Base EntitySet.
        ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectSetResults = Context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        var results = includes == null
            ? objectSetResults.AsQueryable()
            : includes.Aggregate(objectSetResults, (current, include) => current.Include(include.Trim())).AsQueryable();

        // Filter by Where Expression.
        if (whereExpression != null)
        {
            results = results.Where(whereExpression);
        }

        // Order Results.
        if (orderbyProperty != null)
        {
            results = directionIndex > -1
                ? results.OrderByDescending(result => orderbyProperty.GetValue(result, null))
                : results.OrderBy(result => orderbyProperty.GetValue(result, null));
        }

        // Skip Records.
        if ((skippedResults != null) && ((int)skippedResults > 0))
        {
            results = results.Skip((int)skippedResults);
        }

        // Take Specific Amount of records.
        if ((totalResults != null) && (totalResults > 0))
        {
            results = results.Take((int)totalResults);
        }

        // Run the LINQ Query and return the results.
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- Passing in what are essentially booleans that are checked within the
  method is a code smell that should lead you to ask the question "How
  many responsibilities does this method have?".
- I see no reason at all to pass in a string called OrderBy.  I know
  you say that we should just accept that, but I can't think of a
  single good reason not to refactor that to be a Predicate (especially
  since you seem to use it as if it is a Predicate in what must be your
  own custom overloaded extension method).
- The method "GetPrimaryKey" is very misleading in that it apparently
  returns a single string, but a Primary Key can consist of multiple
  columns.
- Another code smell that indicates too many responsibilities (and poor
  naming) are comments explaining simple code.  You should be
  refactoring those blocks into methods or objects.